# codeigniter insert into multiple tables

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table named testimonial . The table structure is as follows.

[image]

But the table dont seem normalized. I would like somthing like.

**trip_testimonial**

```
-----------------------------------
id
trip_id
status
-----------------------------------
```

And another table as

**testimonial**

```
   ----------------------------------
    id
    name
    email
    website
    message
    -----------------------------------
```

But how do I enter the data into them in codeigniter. I have used something like

```
function add($data){

        $this->db->insert('testimonials', $data);
        if($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

What would be the best approach??

Comment: your question is unclear. Do you want to insert into multiple tables? in trip_testimonial what is status?

Comment: the status is just the status for the testimonial which can have either 1 for approved or 0 for pending testimonial

Comment: OK tell me can a single testimonial have multiple trips?

Comment: does the trip_testimonial have a foreign key for testimonial ?

Comment: No, one trip can have multiple testimonials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[TRIP]
trip_id
trip_name
trip_desc
....

[TESTIMONIAL]
testimonial_id
trip_id
testim_name
testim_email
......

function add($data){

  $dataTrip = array(
    //fill the array the appropriate data
  );

  //return the last inserted trip_id
  $lastTripId = $this->myModel->myFuncToAddTrip($dataTrip);    

  $dataTestimonial = array(
   'trip_id' => $lastTripId,
   'testim_name' => $data['testim_name'],
   .......
  );

  if($this->myModel->myFuncAddTestimonial($dataTestimonial)){
   //success
  }else{
   //error
  }

}
```

Use transactions to roll back if at least 1 query fails.

**EDIT**
1 trip to many testimonials

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is normalized for one to one relationship just remove the trip_id column

```
testimonial
-----------------------------------
id
name
email
website
message
date
status
```

Your add function is fine

```
function add($data){

    $this->db->insert('testimonials', $data);
    if($this->db->affected_rows()>0){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

And the data to be inserted

```
$data['name']       =   'blah';
$data['email']      =   'abc@test.com';
$data['website']    =   'website';
$data['message']    =   'message';
$data['date']       =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

And set the default value of status to 0 at table creation or with ALTER.
But when you need to insert you can add one more column with different value.

```
$data['status']     =   1;
```

And now you can call function add
When selecting you can select with status

```
SELECT * FROM testimonial WHERE status = 0
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM testimonial WHERE status = 1
```

UPDATES:

If this is the case than you can do it like this.
Add a column to the testimonials table

```
testimonial
-----------------------------------
id
name
email
website
message
date
status
trip_id
```

Now select trip id

```
    SELECT id FROM trip_testimonial WHERE status = 0
```

And the returned id should be put with testimonial data

```
$data['name']       =   'blah';
$data['email']      =   'abc@test.com';
$data['website']    =   'website';
$data['message']    =   'message';
$data['date']       =   date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$data['trip_id']    =   $row->id;
```

And now call your add function

Comment: No, one trip can have multiple testimonials , so trip_id is the foreign key in trip_testimonials

Comment: thats exactly the same thing that I have posted. But what I want is to Normalize the table as I have stated in the question and insert data into both the table at one in codeigniter]